# IOs in app purchase - reports / transaction log for sandbox

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, sandbox

We have successfully integrated in app purchase and are able to test it in sandbox mode. However, I cannot find anywhere in the docs where to test the records of all purchases made using sandbox account. Somewhere I can test the total amount earned at-least.

I have tried - App analytics, Sales and Trends,  and Payments and Financial Reports   section on appstoreconnect.apple.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no way to check sale/trends for test users. as the Test purchases are sandboxed.

refer to this link:

> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29632